# Localization with Parameter missing some String data

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I created a localisation file and it needed one string parameter

```
static var forget_title: String { 
return  NSLocalizedString("forget_title", value: "Forget \"%@\"?", comment: "forget title") 
}
```

localizable english file is having -

```
"forget_title" = "Forget \"%@\"?";
```

When trying to use it -

```
let name = "XYZ"
let bannerHeader = String(format: .forget_title, name)
print(bannerHeader)
```

result - Forget "XYZ

expected - Forget "XYX"?

So it missing some string Data

Additional Data -

```
let string = "hello \"%@\"?"
let someString = String(format: string, "test")
        
let newString = "hello %@?"
let someOtherString = String(format: newString, "\"test\"")
let bannerHeader = String(format: .forget_title, networkName)
print("Header - \(String.forget_title)")
print("Header - \(someString)")
print("Header - \(someOtherString)")
print("Header - \(bannerHeader)")
```

But if i print bannerHeader first as bellow -

```
print("Header - \(bannerHeader)")
print("Header - \(String.forget_title)")
print("Header - \(someString)")
print("Header - \(someOtherString)")
```

None of the below print statement result is shown in Xcode console.
using xcode - 13.4, swift - Swift 5

Comment: Print `forget_title`. What do you get?

Comment: @Sweeper it is printing - Forget "%@"?

Comment: So everything is good up until `String(format:)`. Check to see if you have any invisible characters in `name` or `forget_title`, then show a [mcve], because I cannot reproduce this with what you have currently provided.

Comment: @Sweeper added additional data -

Comment: Okay, there is definitely a hidden character somewhere now. Please check your strings.

Comment: @Sweeper when i am printing name it is printing - "XYZ" but if i inspect as in hower over it, name is showing data - "XYX\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for suggestion - 

let name = name.filter { $0.isLetter }

let bannerHeader = String(format: .forget_title, name)

print("Header - \(bannerHeader)"

Got the expected result :)

Answer (score 0):

As per @Sweeper suggestion, there were hidden characters in name property -
"XYZ\0\0\0\0\0\0"

So used -

```
let name = name.filter { $0.isLetter }
let bannerHeader = String(format: .forget_title, name)
print("Header - (bannerHeader)"
```

Now getting Expected result - Forget "XYX"?